# 2 divs stacked with a scrollbar

Tags: css

I have 2 divs in a fixed position sidebar, I have been trying to get each of them to have a height that adjusts to fit dynamic elements inside. I got the top one to work with scroll bar but the one on the bottom overflows outside the viewport. Top div has it's height set 200px. Bottom div, If I have height as auto the div doesn't adjust to fit elements, so I use height 100% then div overflows at bottom of page.

How can I have a 200px element on top of another element that fills the remaining page height, each with a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
#top {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background: green;
height: 200px;
width: 100px;
overflow: scroll;
}

#bot {
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background: red;
width: 100px;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
</div>
<div id="bot">
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
test<br />
</div>
```